# What are some examples of injective sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra

Injective objects in the category of abelian groups are precisely the divisible groups. However, despite using injective resolutions of sheaves everywhere, I realized that I did not know a single example of an injective sheaf. I have searched for such examples but unfortunately found none on the internet. What are some easy examples of injective abelian sheaves (if there exist any)?

Comment: See l14 on p11 of https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/rossler/mypage/pdf-files/Intro%20schemes.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godement_resolution

Comment: Thanks a lot, although I was expecting concrete examples. Would've been better to ask as 'interesting examples'.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought the Godement resolution just gave a canonical flasque resolution; I'm not at all sure whether the sheaves it constructs are injective in general?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't know the details, but https://people.math.umass.edu/~gunnells/S20/singspc/resources/full_course.pdf claims the Godement resolution is injective over a field, at least.